# KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false error while using Parse api

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hi I'm newby in android and trying to use `parse Api`. And getting following error in **logcat**.

**Here is my code :**

```
 ParseQuery<User> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
            query.whereEqualTo("phone", phone);

            try {
                List<User> all = query.find();
                Log.v("Size of users are",all.size()+"");
                if (all.size() != 0) {
                    foundUser = true;
                    a = all.get(0);
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**And this is the error in my logcat :**

```
KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure
02-11 17:11:57.871 16766-17225/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest.newTemporaryException(ParseRequest.java:372)
02-11 17:11:57.871 16766-17225/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:198)
02-11 17:11:57.871 16766-17225/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:190)
02-11 17:11:57.871 16766-17225/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
02-11 17:11:57.871 16766-17225/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-11 17:11:57.871 16766-17225/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
02-11 17:11:57.871 16766-17225/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:340)
02-11 17:11:57.871 16766-17225/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:241)
```

Kindly help me how to resolve this issue. I am running code on samsung s6 device.